# I need to prevent url manipulation from accessing parent directory in nginx

Tags: nginx, web-server

Could anyone please advise on the best way to prevent web traffic from succeeding at reaching parent folder using url manipulations such as this:

```
https://www.example.com/../../secret.file/?q=1
```

This is on nginx.

I think I need a location block like so:

```
location 
{
}
```

but I am uncertain as to what kind of regex rule needs to be there. 
Any rule which bans requests with ../ in it should be fine.

Other solutions/suggestions are welcome.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: You do not need to ban these requests. Nginx will not serve files from above the document root.

Answer (score -1):

By default nginx won't let anyone access anything above the root directive. Anyway you might want to block access to some extensions, in which case you'll need something like this rule that denies requests to anything with those extensions:

```
location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
    deny all;
}
```

Check out the nginx documentation too https://nginx.org/en/docs/http